# Statement in $(document).ready( function() not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

We have an `if statement` in our `$(document).ready( function()` that is not being executed. All other components of the function are working properly but this seems to fail every time. `Firebug` shows no errors pertaining to the file and when a breakpoint is set, `Firebug` briefly stops and then loads the page to 100%.

The statement is suppose to retrieve the proper `HTML form` when the `Login` button is hovered over and display it beneath the button. See screen shots. One shows the exact same script working on a different page, in a different `.js` file and one shows it not working but instead an `undefined` message appearing. Both are in massive `js` files, in the `ready` function.

[image: Properly working][image: Not working]

The `$(document).ready` function is 1600+ lines and the problem function is towards the bottom. Here are the statements:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("login-mega-main");
    if (dropdown[0] != null){    
        $.ajax({
            url: '/public/login/dropdown_login.jsp',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) { 
                dropdown[0].innerHTML=response.responseText;
            },
            failure: function(response){
                dropdown[0].innerHTML="<p>Failed to login. Please click 'Login' link</p>";
            }
        }); 
    }
```

The fact that an `undefined` message is appearing instead of the error message tells me that these statements aren't even being reached. And before you say something, yes that `class` exists in the page. The working screenshot and the not-working screenshot have the same `HTML` header.

```
<li><a href="contact/index.jsp">Contact Us</a>
      <li class="login-mega last"><a href="/public/user_profile.jsp"></a>
        <div class="login-mega-main">
            <div class="login-options">
            <form id="login" name="j_security_form" action="/public/j_security_check" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <strong>Account Login</strong><br>
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="j_username"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="text" name="j_password"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"><br>
            <br>
            New users <a href="../user_registration.jsp">register here</a><br>
            <a href="../forgot_password.jsp">Forgot password?</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="auth_mode" value="basic">        
            <script>
            var newloc = document.location.href;
            newloc =newloc.replace('index.jsp','index.jsp');
            document.write('<input type="hidden" name="orig_url" value="'+newloc+'">');
            </script>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>          
        </li>
```

My guess is that the parenthesis are thrown off somewhere but after hours of scouring we couldn't find anything. Since both pages (screenshots) are using identical `HTML` code, we're really at a loss.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: change `dropdown[0].innerHTML=response.responseText;` -> `dropdown[0].innerHTML=response;`

Comment: Can you confirm that the request is being sent using Firebug?

Comment: [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): **success** Type: Function(Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` because `response.responseText` is not defined . Just use `response`

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("login-mega-main");
    if (dropdown[0] != null){

        $.ajax({
            url: '/public/login/dropdown_login.jsp',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) { 
                dropdown[0].innerHTML=response;
            },
            failure: function(response){
                dropdown[0].innerHTML="<p>Failed to login. Please click 'Login' link</p>";
            }
        }); 
    }
```

For better understanding of jQuery [`$.get()` visit here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: This seemed to work. Why does one page prefer resonse over response.responseText?

Comment: @PT_C in that case it may be `XMLHttpRequest object` , `responseText` is the property of that object